# calculate the difference between every point in a series

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to Python/Pandas and was wondering the best/most efficient way to proceed with the following:

I have a panel of data with prices at different locations over time.  The data are originally daily, but I've used the `groupby` functionality to aggregate average *monthly* prices, and get the following (a simplified sample):

```
anomes Market  price         
9508   mkt1    0.298387
       mkt2    0.000000
9509   mkt1    0.254338
       mkt2    0.289787
       mkt3    0.071116
```

Where 'anomes' is a monthly timecode (yy/mm)

My question is, for every time period, what is the best way to calculate the *price difference for each "Market" pair*?

One thought I had would be to "unstack" such that every row represented a single time period, and then iterate that way.  Calling unstack on the df above gives this:

```
          price                    
Market    mkt1    mkt2      mkt3
anomes                              
9508         NaN  0.298387  0.000000
9509    0.254338  0.289787  0.071116
9510    0.255367  0.319558  0.199919
9511    0.341980  0.296720  0.236127
9512    0.420860  0.352125  0.198956
```

and what I would eventually like to have is:

```
           price
Market    mkt1    mkt2      mkt3       mkt1-mkt2     mkt1-mkt3   ...   mkt2-mkt3 ...                                 
9508         NaN  0.298387  0.000000   ...           ...         ...   ...
9509    0.254338  0.289787  0.071116   ...           ...         ...   ...
9510    0.255367  0.319558  0.199919   ...           ...         ...   ...
9511    0.341980  0.296720  0.236127   ...           ...         ...   ...
9512    0.420860  0.352125  0.198956   ...           ...         ...   ...
```

which I would ultimately need to reshape into a "long" format again.

I am somewhat at a loss about how to best accomplish this in Python/Pandas.  Does anyone have any good ideas on the best/most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a concat (and itertools permuations):

```
In [11]: def column_difference(df, colname1, colname2):
             s = df[colname1] - df[colname2]
             s.name = '%s - %s' % (colname1, colname2)
             return s

In [12]: from itertools import permutations

In [13]: pd.concat((column_difference(df, col1, col2) 
                        for col1, col2 in permutations(df.columns, 2)
                        if col1 < col2),  # assuming the column names are orderable (and unique)
                   axis=1)
Out[13]: 
        mkt1 - mkt2  mkt1 - mkt3  mkt2 - mkt3
Market                                       
9508            NaN          NaN     0.298387
9509      -0.035449     0.183222     0.218671
9510      -0.064191     0.055448     0.119639
9511       0.045260     0.105853     0.060593
9512       0.068735     0.221904     0.153169
```

*And you can just concat this result to the original frame...*

Comment: Note: this could be written slightly more robustly using iloc over the columns.

Comment: Awesome, that worked!  Can you elaborate on iloc in this case?

Comment: @user3458221 it's if you had duplicately named columns where it could be a problem, or indeed column names which are unorderable (e.g. ints and strings in python 3). Will edit later, it's basically the same answer!